# Indicator function with Cauchy Schwarz Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, random-variables, independence, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Supposed that $X$ and $Y$ are two non-negative random variable. I want to show that

$$P(\min{(X,Y)} >0) \leq \sqrt{P(X>0)P(Y>0)} $$

My attempt is as follow:
$$P(\min({X,Y})>0) 
= E(I_{\min{(X,Y)}}>0)
= E(I_{X>0}I_{Y>0}) 
= E(I_{X>0})E(I_{Y>0})
$$

if X and Y are independent. Also, it is known that $E(I^2_{X>0}) = E(I_{X>0})$, likewise for Y. We can then apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:

$$
P(\min({X,Y})>0) 
= E(I_{\min{(X,Y)}}>0) 
\leq \sqrt{E(I^2_{X>0})E(I^2_{Y>0})}$$$$
= \sqrt{E(I_{X>0})E(I_{Y>0})}
= \sqrt{P(X>0)P(Y>0)}
$$

which yields the desire result. But I am wondering if there is a way to define two distribution for both $X$ and $Y$ random variable respectively, so that I can establish their independence?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are given the marginal distributions for $X$ and $Y$, their joint distribution is still unspecified, so you cannot impose independence. The result holds even when $X=Y$, and in that case they are not independent.

As a hint to proving this result, observe that either $X=0$ or $X>0$, and either $Y=0$ or $Y>0$. So there are four mutually exclusive combinations of the "state" of $X$ and the "state" of $Y$. See if you can express the inequality in terms of these combinations. (Actually the result holds even if we don't require $X$ and $Y$ to be non-negative.)

Comment: I think I still could not get it, let's day I take X = 0 and Y >0, should I come out with a function to relate the two?

Comment: @arthuranderson  Try this: The event $\{Y>0\}$ is the union of the two events $\{X=0,Y>0\}$ and $\{X>0, Y>0\}$.

Comment: I think I get it, thanks @grand_chat